# Double object construction

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos

I've read that in double object constructions like the following, the indirect object pronoun gets included when there is an indirect object noun.

> Juan le dio un regalo a Martin.
>
> *John gave Martin a gift.*

And I've seen the following double object construction where there are no noun objects.

> Juan se lo dio.
>
> *Juan gave it to him.*
>
> Juan se lo dio a él.
>
> *Juan gave it to him.*

So is this how you say *Juan gave it to Martin*?

> Juan se lo dio a Martin.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *Juan se lo dio a Martin* is correct.

*Juan lo dio a Martin* is correct too, but that misses the point of using the double object construction.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "`Juan se lo dio a Martín`". `Juan lo dio a Martín` sounds strange.